# Disable a button, when a Task is completed

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I have a method, that checks if a button can be pressed or not, if my file path or the language is null, I don't enable the button, and of course, when my file path is selected, I raise the event.

So right now I am doing some work on Azure, and I want to disable the button when I start my work and enable it when I finished my work.

I tried to raise the event, before the call o the method and after the call, but it doesn't enable the button

```
        public string? FilePath { get; set; }

        public bool IsWorking { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<int, Languages>? LanguagesDictionary { get; set; }

        public Visibility CanShow { get; set; }

        public DialogHelper DialogHelper { get; }

        public FolderHelper FolderHelper { get; }

        public AudioHelper AudioHelper { get; }

        public AzureTranscriptionService AzureTranscription { get; }

        public Command PickFileCommad { get; set; }

        public Command StartCommand { get; set; }

        private string? _SelectedItem;

        public string SelectedItem {
            get => _SelectedItem!;
            set {
                if (_SelectedItem != value) {
                    _SelectedItem = value;
                    StartCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public AudioPageViewModel() {
            InitListLanguages();
            AzureTranscription = new AzureTranscriptionService();
            DialogHelper = new DialogHelper();
            FolderHelper = new FolderHelper();
            AudioHelper = new AudioHelper();
            CanShow = Visibility.Hidden;
            PickFileCommad = new Command(PickFileAction);
            StartCommand = new Command(StartAction, CanStartAction);
        }

        private bool CanStartAction(object arg) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedItem) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath) ||
                IsWorking == true) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private async void StartAction(object obj) {

            var FileWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension
                (FilePath);

            var AudioPath = FolderHelper.CreateFolder(ConstantsHelpers.AUDIO);

            var DocumentPath = FolderHelper.CreateFolder();

            var AudioFileNamePath = Path.Combine(AudioPath, $"{FileWithoutExtension}{ConstantsHelpers.WAV}");

            var ConvertedAudioPath = AudioHelper.Converter(FilePath!, AudioFileNamePath);

            var DocumentName = Path.Combine(DocumentPath, $"{FileWithoutExtension}{ConstantsHelpers.DOCX}");

            IsWorking = true;

            StartCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

            await AzureTranscription.ConvertToTextAsync(ConvertedAudioPath,
                SelectedItem, DocumentName);

            IsWorking = false;
            StartCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();


        }

        private void PickFileAction() {
            var FullPath = DialogHelper.GetFilePath(ConstantsHelpers.AUDIO);
            FilePath = FullPath;

            StartCommand?.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
```

```
 public async Task ConvertToTextAsync(
            string FilePath,
            string Language,
            string WordDocName) {

            // Configure speech service

            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(ConstantsHelpers.AZURE_KEY, ConstantsHelpers.AZURE_REGION);
            config.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = Language;
            // Configure speech recognition

            var taskCompleteionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

            using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(FilePath);
            using var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioConfig);
            speechRecognizer.Recognizing += SpeechRecognizer_Recognizing;
            speechRecognizer.Recognized += SpeechRecognizer_Recognized;
            speechRecognizer.SessionStarted += SpeechRecognizer_SessionStarted;
            speechRecognizer.SessionStopped += SpeechRecognizer_SessionStopped;

            await speechRecognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            Task.WaitAny(new[] { taskCompleteionSource.Task });

            await speechRecognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        private void SpeechRecognizer_SessionStopped(object? sender, SessionEventArgs e) {

            Debug.WriteLine("Stepped");
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var item in Letters) {
                sb.Append(item);
            }
        }

        private void SpeechRecognizer_SessionStarted(object? sender, SessionEventArgs e) {

            Debug.WriteLine("Started");
        }
        private void SpeechRecognizer_Recognized(object? sender, SpeechRecognitionEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
                foreach (var item in e.Result.Text) {
                    Letters.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        private void SpeechRecognizer_Recognizing(object? sender, SpeechRecognitionEventArgs e) {

            Debug.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
        }
    }
```

When I start working, I execute this code

Many thanks

Comment: `Task.Wait` and `Task.WaitAny` will introduce a potential deadlock and forces synchronous execution. You should always use `await` to wait for a Task to complete. The equivalent asynchronous snippet would be: `await Task.WhenAny`. Once the awaited Task returns, you can set a flag that is checked by the CanExecute delegate of the ICommand that is bound to the Button. If CanExecute returns `false` the Button will disable itself.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of code

Comment: You have not provided enough code to give you an example. Simply introduce a private bool property. Then await ConvertToTextAsync. Then, when await continues set this property to false. Let CanExecute delegate of the ICommand check for this property.

Comment: What information do you need

Comment: that is why I created isWorking

Comment: How is Command implemented. Does it use the CommandManager?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248983/discussion-between-eduardo-gomez-and-bioniccode).

Comment: Also make sure that your CanStartAction returns the correct value.

Comment: What do you mean by returning the appropriate value, is a method associated with a button

Comment: What is the TaskCompletionSource for? You don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the below refactorings don't help, debug your program:

- check if `CanStartAction` is actually called and returns the expected result.
- probably the asynchronous method returns too fast for your eye to see the button being disabled. Modify your code as follows to test this:

```cs
await AzureTranscription.ConvertToTextAsync(ConvertedAudioPath,
                SelectedItem, DocumentName);
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

In general, move the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` request to the relevant property setters to keep your code clean.

```cs
private bool isBusy;
private bool IsBusy 
{ 
  get => this.isBusy; 
  set
  {
    this.isBusy = value;
    this.StartCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
  }
}

private bool CanStartAction(object arg) 
{
  return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedItem) &&
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath) &&
    !this.IsBusy
}

private async void StartAction(object obj) 
{ 
  this.IsBusy = true;

  var fileWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension
                (FilePath);
  var audioPath = FolderHelper.CreateFolder(ConstantsHelpers.AUDIO);
  var documentPath = FolderHelper.CreateFolder();
  var audioFileNamePath = Path.Combine(audioPath, $"{FileWithoutExtension}{ConstantsHelpers.WAV}");
  var convertedAudioPath = AudioHelper.Converter(FilePath!, audioFileNamePath);
  var documentName = Path.Combine(documentPath, $"{fileWithoutExtension}{ConstantsHelpers.DOCX}");

  await AzureTranscription.ConvertToTextAsync(convertedAudioPath,
                this.SelectedItem, documentName);

  this.IsBusy = false;
}

public async Task ConvertToTextAsync(string FilePath,
  string Language,
  string WordDocName) 
{
  ...
  
  // Using Task.Wait, Task.WaitAny and Task.WaitAll will execute a Task synchronously and introduces a potential deadlock.
  // To avoid this, always await a Task and use Task.WhenAny and Task.WhenAll instead
  await Task.WhenAny(new[] { taskCompleteionSource.Task });
  
  // Or because you only have to wait for a single Task write
  await taskCompleteionSource.Task;

  ...
}
```

See [C# Naming guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines)

Comment: Thank you, but the button doesn't get enable

Comment: I am sorry, it works fine, what I need to figure out is why my Azure method doesn't work

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have not downvoted your post. I would ask you to post a new question related to your Azure API call. It is not related to this question.

Comment: In general, when using any services like Azure or Google services, make sure your application is properly authenticated.